# Ban [dynamic] tag

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tag-block-request

There are [1,596 questions tagged *dynamic*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic) on Stack Overflow: most of them seem to be from people not understanding that spaces separate tags (that is, they're talking about dynamic *term*).

Notwithstanding the intent of the usage of the tag, *Dynamic* adds no information on its own, only modifies another term: I don't think anyone would ever just want to find *dynamic* questions, but dynamic *term* questions. This should be banned like other meta tags.

**Edit:** one other reference point, [The Death of Meta Tags](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/), describes two criteria that likely point to a meta tag:

> 1. **If the tag can’t work as the only tag on a question, it’s probably a meta-tag.** Every tag you use should be able to work, more or less, as the only tag on a question. Meta-tags, like [beginner], [subjective], and [best-practices], are useless by themselves — they tell you nothing at all about the content of the question.
>    2. **If the tag commonly means different things to different people, it’s probably a meta-tag.** In a cruel, ironic twist, the meaning of the tag [subjective] itself … is actually subjective. Ditto for [best-practices] and [beginner]. Best practices to whom? Beginner by what criteria? These tags are impossible to define by anything remotely resembling an objective metric. In comparison, the the meaning of tags like [java], [c#], and [javascript] are crystal clear to all but the nuttiest of nutbags.

While these criteria are not necessary and sufficient to define a meta tag, the *dynamic* tag seems to meet both criteria.

**Edit 2:** it'd be helpful, for me at least, to understand where my argument has gone wrong to warrant the down votes.

Currently, the two answers are:

1. That *dynamic* is an important modifier tag to C#, F# and other related languages, which supports criteria 1 (that it can't stand on its own), and
2. That there are at least some legitimate uses of *dynamic*, but the meaning of the tag changes depending on context, which supports criteria 2 (that it commonly means different things to different people).

So why should it be kept?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I went through the first 60 as Mark linked them and tried to judge how [dynamic] is being used.

Categories of usage:

- **Marketing speak**: 3
- **dynamic-foo**: 18 (ip:1 loading:5 memory-management:1 binding:1 pivot:1 html:1 array:2 domain:1 select-menus:1 images:1 programming:1 expansion:1 list:1)
- **Hard to classify or pointless**: 4
- **In lieu of "polymorphic", "at runtime", or similar**: 20
- **.Net keyword**: 8
- **something htmly to do with divs**: 2 (maybe put this with the dynamic-foos?)
- **"dynamic LINQ expression"**: 2 (maybe put this with the dynamic-foos?)
- **in a reflexive language setting**: 2

(doesn't add up. I must have dropped a couple)

Some of these are rather out of my ken, but it looks like a few may be legitimate. Certainly the marketing speak can go and the dynamic-foos should be joined up.

I notice that the html folks use a bare dynamic a lot to differentiate from static pages. (This accounts for many of the ones I've marked as "at runtime", the div usages seems to be separate from that.)

The use in a reflexive context seems pretty natural to me, though there may be a better word.

---

BTW-- I'll make this CW and invite more knowledgeable folks to join up categories where appropriate.

Comment: This seems to support that the *dynamic* tag is meaningless on its own and is indeed a meta tag.

Answer (score 8):

It is a keyword that was recently added to the C# language.  Which makes it an important contextual tag when the [C#] tag is used.  A question that is tagged [C#] [dynamic] is clearly asking about how to use the new support for dynamic programming in C#.  Also relevant to the [.NET], [VB.NET] and [F#] tags.  We need to keep it for just this reason.

Comment: Wouldn't `[c#-dynamic]` (or similar) be more appropriate? Most other scope-specific tags follow that pattern.

Comment: This is supported by my survey (I seem to have 8 such uses out of 60 examined).

Comment: Granted it's a small sample, but if only 13% of the cases are categorically legitimate, doesn't that seem to support the idea that the tag is not particularly useful on its own? Tags are meant to work by themselves, which *dynamic* does not do.

Comment: @mark: the flip side is [const] currently with 355 uses, [extern] with 86, and [struct] with 760. Perhaps not an exact analogy as these keywords are used in many languages with c-like syntax, but...

Comment: A tag like [c#-dynamic] is not useful, you just can't create an effective query anymore.  An expert on using dynamic programming in C# will create a query that includes *both* [c#] and [dynamic].  *And* it has good odds of finding Jon Skeet.

Comment: Maybe `[dynamic-keyword]` or `[dynamic-dotnet]`?