# View counter seems to be broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, meta, views

On Stackoverflow there are several answered questions with zero views.

In lists like these: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net?sort=newest&pagesize=15

Or in the questions themselves: [ASP --> ASP.Net: Refactoring steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582134/asp-asp-net-refactoring-steps)

[image]

Edit: Also on meta now: [Ban [dynamic] tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62495/ban-dynamic-tag)

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem. Happening on this page as well.

Comment: This question has zero views, too, yet I have viewed it. We are nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry, bug. The responsible parties are being beaten as I type this.

Comment: by unicorns with waffles?

Comment: @Tobias, no, [waffles](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/17174/waffles "Sam Saffron") wouldn't hurt a fly!