# Why doesn't my question have zero views?

Tags: discussion, questions, views

Why is the minimum question view count not 0? I have never seen (if it's not [buggy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62501/view-counter-seems-to-be-broken)) a view count less than 1. Even for my own just published question.

Is it viewed by me? If that is true — what is the reason to make it 1, not 0?

Comment: @ShadowWizard please revise you action.

Comment: OK. What about [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259441/what-is-that-1-view-which-automatically-appears-after-submitting-a-question)? (If you agree it's dupe, you can close it yourself with one vote)

Comment: @ShadowWizard seems same. But that answers are not clear for me. I.e. why view counter count my own view, but I can't say vote for my own question as `usefull`? When I publish question I want to know other people interest (view count/votes/favs) about question, not my own.

Comment: You can only see the number of views on the question page, so you've already viewed it... ergo, min 1 view.

Comment: But you are not the only one using that information... Every user is. You are a user, so your view is counted.

Comment: @Catija if so, I could vote for my post as another user, but I can't.

Comment: Voting gives rep, views don't. Not the same at all.

Comment: I usually have to view my question while asking them. The one view is you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While it's true that views can give badges, a single view really doesn't count towards anything.

The minimum views that have any effect are 1000, giving a [Popular Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/26/popular-question) badge. One view out of 1000 is really really minor.

Also, if you compare this to voting, voting is an active action: user has to explictly click something to perform this action. Views are passive actions: they are recorded behind the scenes, without any explicit action from the user causing them.

Last but not least, I am pretty sure that technically the views field starts indeed at 0, and updated whenever someone visits a question. Since the code automatically redirects the user to their question after posting it, the code updating the views executes, unaware who views the question.