# Inconsistency between view count for profile and view count for question

Tags: bug, profile-page, views

I had never seen view count for question less than one, but frequently I see zero count of views for the new users profile:

> [image: 0 views]

You could make sure by checking [most of the new users from the list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=NewUsers&sort=creationdate).

I think view count for profile should be fixed according the answer on [my old question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/284946/339911) about counting for question's views.

Comment: Question views starts at 1 because it auto counts your view when you initially ask the question; I guess the profile views either doesn't count your views or it's cached and it isn't showing your view *yet*.

Comment: @Cai `0 views` is confusing me. I offer to never show `0 views` at all. Easy workaround is to add `if (views == 0) ++views;` somewhere. P.S. one time I see `viewed 1 time` for an another user question (don't know how to reproduce).

Answer (score 2):

For the question view count, it uses server logs and IP address counts to count the number of question views: this is not user-bound/specific! From the server log, there is no distinction between the question asker or someone else. The cache holds for 15 minutes, after that your view is counted as a new one.

The profile page number is solely the number of views from other users. Not sure how they measure this, but I am pretty sure the way this is calculated is different.

There is no need to start with 1 and count your own profile views with it. What would be the benefit of that?

Comment: I'm not looking for any benefits, I just would like to know: why 0 views for the profile page is OK, but 0 views for the question is bad.

Comment: Why do you think 0 views for questions is bad? It is just a technical thing.

Comment: Is it too hard to substract/add 1 to make counts consistent?

Comment: For what? Why???

Comment: At least for uniformity.

Comment: Of two unrelated properties? Why?

Comment: They are not unrelated, they are both **views**. 0 views means that no one seen. It's wrong to show me `0 views` for the page on which I'm looking right now.