# Should the "dynamic" tag have a description in its wiki?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

[Ok, so we're keeping the](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62495/ban-dynamic-tag) [dynamic](/questions/tagged/dynamic) tag.  It's now the most popular tag *without a description* (until just now, I have supplied a description, largely based on the answer supplied to the linked question). It's unusual for being overloaded with many, useful meanings.

Should the tag-wiki elaborate on these different meanings?
Should it stand with no description?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes**, definitely add a tag wiki and a tag wiki excerpt!

I can't imagine a situation where it would ever be preferable to have *no* description. Even if the description is not complete (as it might not be here), something is better than nothing. And people can continue to add on to the existing tag wiki in the future, as other common uses are observed.

The only real question is whether a tag with so many different meanings is useful at all. But that's already been covered by the linked discussion and seems tangential to what you're asking here. If we've decided to keep the tag in spite of its possible flaws, then creating a tag wiki explaining its menagerie of meanings is definitely the best way of coping with the situation.

Comment: Thats kind of what I thought (and why I went ahead and added one anyway) but it was conspicuous in its absence.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy: There are lots of tags missing their wiki. That's a consequence of not enough people knowing about the possibility of editing tag wikis, not having enough time, and there being an *enormous* number of tags on SO.